# Git --find-renames --find-copies order affects results

Tags: git

I staged a file that is a copy of another file already in the repository. Now, if i run

```
git diff --cached --find-copies --find-renames
```

I get

```
...
similarity index 100%
...
```

But when I run

```
git diff --cached --find-renames --find-copies
```

I get

```
...
new file mode 100644
...
```

I'm using https://git-for-windows.github.io/, version: `git version 2.6.3.windows.1`

`diff.renames` is set to `copies`

Why does it behave this way and how can I make it always show copies?